# Windows 8 upgrade on multiple PCs

Tags: windows-8, license

I bought windows 8 upgrade from [microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/buy?ocid=GA8_O_WOL_Hero_ShopHP_FPP_Null), and i found on [this page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/buy?ocid=GA8_O_WOL_Hero_ShopHP_FPP_Null) that:

> - Offer valid from October 26, 2012 until January 31, 2013 and is for individuals and small businesses needing to **upgrade up to five**
>     devices. If you are a business customer looking to upgrade more than
>     five devices to Windows 8 Pro, contact your Microsoft partner for more
>     information

Is that means that i Can upgrade up to five PCs using the same downloaded windows? or means that I can buy max 5 licences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it means that if you have more than 5 devices, rather than paying for five retail upgrades you'll get better pricing by opening a volume licensing account.

Comment: so this means that the version i just got is just for one device upgrade and can't use it for any other device in the same time, correct?

Comment: That is correct.